# Java Hello World Desktop Application

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-rcp, awt, desktop-application

I would like to see how to create a hello world java desktop application using Eclipse. I know Java very well, but I have never created a Java desktop application. It would be great if someone could provide an example. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website.  A quick google search on Java Eclipse and Tutorial gave me many results. Perhaps you can check one of them out and post more specific questions here?

Answer (score 3):

The essential element of a Swing application is a top-level `JFrame` (window). We'll add a single component (a `JLabel`) so there's some content in the `JFrame`, call `pack()` so the components are laid out, then make the frame visible. All this goes inside the standard `main()` method for a Java application, though for real applications you'd probably want to organise the code into other methods so that `main()` doesn't get too bloated.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame hello = new JFrame("Hello World");
        hello.add(new JLabel("Hello World"));
        hello.pack();
        hello.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean with a gui?  most people would use swing which there is a plugin for eclipse to help in building swing ui's.  if you dont need a gui then just create a class and in the main method put

```
    class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String args[]){

System.out.println("Hello World");

}//end main

}
```

then compile the code

> javac HelloWorld.java

Then run your compiled code

> java HelloWorld

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html)

Comment: It does need a gui. But even with your example how will I get a desktop application ? Is there an exe file or something that gets created when I run the eclipse project ?

Comment: check updates added.  it will not be exe as its a Java application.  So it will be .java

Comment: Creating an .exe for your Eclipse-RCP app is not only possible, it's also very easy to do.  Take a look here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F

Comment: owengerig - I see the .java and .class files. But I am trying to get a desktop application. I'd like my program to run when I double click the application.

Comment: @stracka - In the tutorial it says go to Plug-in Development, but I dont have that available in my eclipse. I tried installing new software, but I couldn't find anything related to the Plug-in development. I also looked in the list of available perspectives and I couldn't find that option there as well.

Comment: Did you download the RCP version of Eclipse? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/junor

Comment: there is another method. you make it a jar file instead of a .java and configure windows (http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/387943) or (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0166.html).  This makes it executable not .exe though